# Array of "Object" class

Tags: java, arrays, object

Despite the fact that you lose the typing security, is it bad to use primitive Object class arrays to be able to have a multi-typed array?

Code to understand:

```
public class testobject {

    public static void main (String[] args){

        Object[] obj = new Object[5];
        obj[0] = "Cat";
        obj[1] = 7;
        obj[2] = new Object();

        for(int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
            System.out.println(obj[i]);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You should not do that.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: It is not a problem, it is a conceptual question. I do this all the time in PHP, so I wondered if there was a relative in Java. Its unsecure, but in some simple situations it is useful.

Comment: Yes, it's bad.  It's lazy, not type safe, and you're far better off creating an actual class to hold your data in correctly typed, named fields.

Comment: I think there are no other problems - but the missing type security is bad enough

Comment: Yes, it's bad. Types are important and useful, it's better to keep them. Besides, using raw arrays is very seldom useful; you're very, very often better off using a `List<T>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is bad to use `Object[]` as a completely generic array *because* you lose type security.

Java is a strongly typed language. This has many benefits, the main one being that many runtime errors are caught at compile time if you code well. If you try to fight that (by making everything `Object` and friends) you're going against Java's natural incentives and you're going to have a hard time.

Let's say you initialize an `Object[]` that is specifically full of strings, like such:

```
Object[] arr = {"Hello", "World"};
```

But then you want the length of the first strings. You can't just do the following

```
int len = arr[0].length();
```

Because java no longer knows that arr[0] is a String. Instead you have to explicitly do a cast to string to use the method

```
int len = ((String) arr[0]).length();
```

Instead if you had initialized the array as `String[]` you can call string methods on any of the objects you get out of the array, because they must be `String`s.

```
String[] arr = {"Hello", "World");
int len = arr[0].length(); //--> 5
```

**TL;DR** : Java is strongly typed. Embrace that, don't fight it. You'll thank me later.

Comment: Very good and direct explanation. The use of type specific methods nailed it.